# Get complete zone records from DNS, DNSJava doesn't return all records

Tags: java, dns

Good afternoon,

I'm working on a network discovery effort, and need to get all records for a domain.  When I use DNSJava, its not the complete set.  CNAME's aren't present, and not all TXT records, or A records.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Here's my code:

```
    package iMCDNS;
    import java.util.Hashtable;

    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
    import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
    import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
    import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
    import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

    import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
    import org.xbill.DNS.Record;
    import org.xbill.DNS.Type;

    public class iMCDNS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Running iMCDNS");

        try {

            //this returned no records

//          DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
//          Attributes atts = ctx.getAttributes("iditsecurity.com", new String[] {"CNAME"});
//          
//          System.out.println("Attributes size: " + atts.size());
//
//          NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> e = atts.getAll();
//          
//          
//          while(e.hasMore()) {
//              System.out.println(e.next().get());
//          }

            //this also returns no CNAME records
            Record[] rs = new Lookup("iditsecurity.com", Type.ANY).run();

            if (rs!=null)
            {
                int javaDNSLen = rs.length;

                for (int i = 0;i < javaDNSLen; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("record: " + rs[i].toString());
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("No records found");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + ex.toString());
        }



    }




    }
```

And the results provided:
Should have 2 A records, 4 CNAME and 5 TXT records...

```
Running iMCDNS
record: iditsecurity.com.   4503    IN  TXT "google-site-verification=VvXfVc-hr0dK3pzjc3yiAaDsK-tlFAMX7Xt3soYXByc"
record: iditsecurity.com.   4503    IN  TXT "google-site-verification=8W17El_6uLvJ0WLxEsgIKt9hKRPuz6yN9U_ke9l0i7E"
record: iditsecurity.com.   4360    IN  MX  10 mx1.netsolmail.net.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define "get all records for a domain" more precisely.
Also, in passing, if you are at apex of a zone, you can not have `CNAME` records because they can not coexist with any other ones, and apex already has `NS` and `SOA` records by design.

Second, do not use type `ANY` to do your DNS queries. For whatever reasons this is read as `ALL` but it does not have this semantic at all and will not produce the results you expect. `ANY` towards a recursive caching nameserver will get you back the list of current records in the resolver cache, which is **NOT** all records related to the domain. There is in fact work to deprecate completely this (virtual) type, see: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any/ (and more explanations in non technical terms at https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2016/09/07/dns-any-requests-are-deprecated/ or https://blog.cloudflare.com/what-happened-next-the-deprecation-of-any/)

So then you will ask: This is fine, but then how to do it?

It then loops back to first point. You will need to define with record types you want (`A`, `AAAA`, `TXT`, etc.) and then loop over them to retrieve all of them.
It is not always simple as that for at least two reasons:
* `TXT` is becoming nowadays a catch all and transports a lot of things: SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc.
* and specifically for DKIM or the same for SRV in fact, you need to query domains with a specific structure (like `_service._transport.example.com` for SRV) so you can not "auto-discover" all records, you need to know which one you need (or start with a list to test)

I would also recommend that you specify which nameservers you are using, because if it is a recursive one you will gain get results from its cache, with the associated TTL which may or may not be what you want/need. So you may be better querying the (one) authoritative nameserver of the domain.